# Meteor accounts-base - Log out without unstore token

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I use accounts-base for my project, and I would like to open a connection from external people during x days.

To open this connection, I create a token (`Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken`)
and I insert it in a special user (`Accounts._insertLoginToken`).

Next I can login with this token (`Accounts.loginWithToken`).

The problem is when I log out, this destroy my token whereas I would like the possibility to reconnect to this token.

How can I do that ? Is there a way the add an options or something to bypass the `this._unstoreLoginToken()` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's destroyed and not just removed from local storage? In your mongo shell there should even after logout be a field `services.resume.loginTokens`.

Comment: In my mongo, when i log in with my token, i have `services.resume.loginTokens` as array with one element (corresponding to my token). Then when i call `Meteor.logout()`, i always have `loginTokens` but it is an empty array.